# fatal exception: java.lang.RuntimeException. Barcode scanner code crashes on device, works on emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am working on [the barcode scanner example](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3) and have been making it work fine on the emulator. But when I load it on my droid 2, it crashes when I click the "scan code" button. Here is the error in logcat below. What am I missing?

```
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mds.tutorial.ca/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mds.tutorial.ca-1.apk]
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1618)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mds.tutorial.ca-1.apk]
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-12 14:40:36.200  2962  2962 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1610)
```

Thanks.

here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mds.tutorial.ca"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name=".CaActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" 
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
           <!-- ZXing activities --> 
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"> 
        <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" android:label="@string/share_name">
        <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
        </intent-filter>            
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems dalvik couldnt find your class. Make sure your launching activity package definition is correct in manifest file. If correct, I would do complete uninstall of app from phone and do reinstall.

Comment: everything seems correct, and I'm running this while connected to the phone in debug mode so I can see my changes quickly without having to install. I have posted my manifest in the updated question.

Comment: What is this class com.xzing....? Is this your class? I understand you are doing this in debug mode, still you can do complete uninstall of the app and reinstall. Just to make sure you have fresh version.

Comment: the xzing is a google barcode processing library. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: just checking..  your zxing android library was created from phonegap plugin zipped download, right? And not from the link you give above?